# Reading xls file like mysql

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have an excel file which gets updated each day.  Is it possible to query the xls file as if you wood within an mysqldb.

such as `select * from *excel sheet name* where colmn1 = '1'`

Comment: I don't think you can with .xls, but if you convert them into .csv, then you have got everything you need in php to process .csv files!

Comment: You can use the command-line version of excel2mysql to upload the xls to a mysql table each night.  Then you can write execute a standard mysql query to the table in php.  If you must read the xls directly, you will have to write a great deal of custom logic using something like the Microsoft COM objects, but it won't be in the form of a query.